# how to make a button call a find() functtion in server.js > mongdb and show it in html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating this web app using node express and mongodb atlas.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    User.find({firstName: 'vinicius', (err, users) =>{
        res.render('index', {
            userList: users
        })
    })
})
```

with this piece of code I can retrieve the data with first name 'vinicius' and show it on the html with the following:

```js
<%userList.forEach(users =>{%><p><%= user.firstName %></p><%})%>
```

my challenge is: i want to create a buton on html to call this query
in fact i would like to have an input field where i can put the cpf number (it's like the social security number), that is, i write the CPF and then query it and it returns on the page
and another button where i can query all information and show it on brower (i can do the rule of all, it would be writtn in the user find().

just dont know how to call it from the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button with a click listener like this:

```
<button id="someid" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to fetch user</h3>
```

Then, inside you script, you should have a function called `myFunction` that is called when the button is pressed.

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
  // Here you can grab your input field by id, and pass its value to your API

  // Do you API call and populate data on the frontend
}
</script>
```

Here's how you can use the fetch API to do your API call:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Here's how you can grab and mutate HTML elements:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp